# Did Israelis build bunkers and tunnels under al-Shifa hospital, and if so why?

Tags: israel, gaza, fact-check-request

[Sky News](https://news.sky.com/story/israel-gaza-latest-hamas-hostage-ceasefire-truce-sky-news-live-blog-updates-12978800?postid=6769670#liveblog-body):

> "We all know there are bunkers and tunnels because the Israelis built some of them when they were in control of the al Shifa hospital before 2005," he [Sky News military analyst Michael Clarke] said.

Is that confirmed from Israeli sources? What was the purpose of those "bunkers and tunnels" under the hospital if/when Israelis built them?

Comment: Not sure why the DV. IIRC someone wrote in another answer here Israel had some laws requiring bunkers since the 1970s, but IDK if they applied to the OPTs too. Also, hospitals can have underground stuff for other operational reasons. And yeah, they could have been built long before there was a Hamas threat/habit of using tunnels. FWTW https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Shifa_Hospital mentions the current allegations of Hamas using those under the hospital, but there's no word on who might have built [any] of them.

Comment: Not my DV but maybe the question isn't seen as interesting/useful enough. This is probably motivated by actual events, but might be rather of marginal interest especially one year from now or longer.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution: well, I can ask on skeptics, but the 'why' part might not be suitable there since no purpose is claimed in the post.

Comment: That article link doesn't go anywhere useful, since it's just the live update feed.  Can you link to a specific article?

Comment: @Fizz,  Nice find +1.  Never heard that before.   Something for me to read up on when I get a moment.  thank you.  Perhaps they were built protect hospital staff and patients given Israel occupied Gaza for decades.  Given Gaza's proximity to Egypt and the many wars between Egypt and Israel over Israel's history this was likely a reasonable concern in the late 1960's  and 70's.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to Hebrew wikipedia, on the "Shifa Hospital" page, Israel **constructed a concrete underground basement in the al-Shifa hospitol** (Google translation):

> In the 1980s, Israel renovated and expanded the hospital complex with American assistance; Among other things, the project, which was managed by the coordinator of government operations in the territories, Shmuel Goren, included the **construction of an underground concrete floor**, a new dialysis wing inaugurated in August 1989[6] and a new six-story wing inaugurated in December 1990.[7] The architects Gershon Tzpoor and the late Benjamin Idelson were hired by a consulting firm to design the Princess Aaliya Hospital in Hebron and the Shifa Hospital in Gaza in the 1980s.

It however remains an enigma why exactly this floor was constructed. Was it for security reasons? It might as well be for architectural reasons, in order to reinforce the whole building, so more floors can be added on top of it, or to make the building earthquake proof etc. (I think most normal hospitals have a concrete basement).

https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%90

Comment: "Floor" does not mean that "bunkers and tunnels" were constructed. If there was cellar without floor (ground only, as I have seen in some buildings), they maybe just added the floor to have it more useful.

Comment: @Stančikas, accordingly it seems that Sky News calling a concrete basement "bunkers and tunnels", is just bla bla talk.

Comment: To allow for more heights or protect against earthquakes, you build deeper and better foundations. Underground floors are a risk for the integrity of the building as they are basically, well, empty space.

Comment: sturdy, multi-level basements are a feature of most hospitals. They have less EMI/RFI for imaging devices (as well as keeping them away from others), it's a safer place to put the isotope reactors, samples/specimens and I.T. need less HVAC, records are safer from disasters, etc...

Answer (score 5):

I don't have any information about this specific hospital, but since 1951, it's been part of Israeli law that "all homes, residential buildings and industrial buildings in Israel are required to have bomb shelters." (quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_defense_in_Israel#Shelters)).

So it is highly likely that the hospital has some kind of underground shelter which was constructed to comply with Israeli law when the area was under Israeli control.  I believe such things are also registered with the appropriate government department, so the IDF would know what it originally looked like.

Of course, since Hamas has been in control of the area since 2007 and thus the hospital was no longer subject to Israeli law, it could have been drastically altered, but the original shelter was almost certainly Israeli.

Comment: @Fizz - I hope this is enough "Why" to answer your question.  I could probably go into why the law is what it is, but that seemed like overkill for the question.

Comment: Does that law apply to the Occupied Territories though? Those are generally ruled under Jordanian law and military orders, IIRC. Otherwise most Palestinians would probably have a rocket/bomb shelter in their houses, like the Israelis do.

Comment: @Fizz - The better question is whether it applied back in the 1980's, which is really hard to find information on right now.  My impression is that a significant subset of Israeli law applied at the time, but I don't know if this one was part of it.